# rpart package issue in R 3.0.1 version

Tags: r, rpart

i am newbie to R
 i am using R 3.0.1 version,
I have installed rpart package using 
install.packages("rpart") 
selected USA(CA 1) in the pop up box and it is installed successfully

```
> p_data = read.csv(file="/home/sudeep/Desktop/mysql.tsv",sep="\t",dec=".",header=TRUE)
> dtree <- rpart(paid ~ .,data = p_data, method="class")
Error: could not find function "rpart"
```

so what is wrong with me??

Answer (score 9):

You don't actually need to install rpart manually; it comes with the base R distribution. However, you *do* need to *load* it into your R session with a call to `library`:

```
library(rpart)
rpart(paid ~ ., data=....)
```